# How to copy a column to an other column in an SQlite data base with kotlin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

I have an `SQlite` data base in an android app developted in kotlin. In this data base I store objects of this `class`

> class Device_info

```
class Device_info {
var id : Int = 0
var name : String = ""

constructor(id : Int, name: String){
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Now in the `id` variable I want to store the `raw_id` that the data base will automaticaly give. I have found in some tutorials how to create a data base handler and I have made it like this

> data base handler class

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

private const val DATABASE_NAME = "Devices_db"
private const val TABLE_NAME = "Devices"
private const val RAW_ID = "raw_id"
private const val COLUMN_NAME = "name"
private const val COLUMN_ID = "id"




class DataBaseHandler(var context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + RAW_ID +
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER)"

        db?.execSQL(createTable)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {}


    fun insertData(device: Device_info){
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()

        cv.put(COLUMN_ID, device.id)
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, device.name)
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)

        db.close()
    }

    fun readData() : MutableList<Device_info>{
        val list : MutableList<Device_info> = ArrayList()
        val db = this.readableDatabase

        val query = "Select * from " + TABLE_NAME
        val result = db.rawQuery(query, null)

        if(result.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                val device = Device_info()

                device.id = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)).toInt()
                device.name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)    
                list.add(device)

            }while(result.moveToNext())
        }

        result.close()
        db.close()

        return list
    }


    fun UpdateId(device: Device_info){
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()

        cv.put(COLUMN_ID, device.id)

        db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "id = " + device.id, null)

        db.close()
    }

    fun UpdateName(device: Device_info){
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, device.name)
        cv.put(COLUMN_ID, device.id)

        db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "id = " + device.id, null)

        db.close()
    }



    fun deleteData(device: Device_info){
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()

        cv.put(COLUMN_ID, device.id)
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, device.name)
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id = " + device.id, null)

        db.close()
    }
}
```

So after I create an object by passing in the constructor the name and as an `id` `-1`, because at the time I don't know the `raw_id` as I haven't added the object in the data base, I call the function `insertData` and the object is succesfully stored in the data base but the column `id` contains `-1` to all elemnts. My question is how can I copy the `raw_id` column in the `id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have two columns that are storing exactly the same value? Unless you are then going to manipulate id's which would not be recommended.

Accessing just the one column raw_id would be more efficient. It wouldn't waste space, it would allow more data to be cached and so on.

I guess the clue as to your intention is in *because at the time I don't know the raw_id as I haven't added the object in the data base* In that you basically want to know what the **id** is. The following is how you could retrieve the **id** (raw_id) :-

You retrieve the value returned from the **insert** and return that from the **insertData** method.

Something like :-

```
fun insertData(device: Device_info): Long{
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val cv = ContentValues()

    cv.put(COLUMN_ID, device.id)
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, device.name)
    val rv = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv)
    db.close()
    return rv
}
```

Comment: So the `db.insert` method returns the `raw_id` ?

Comment: @KyriafinisBill Yes. Or to be more precise it returns the hidden **rowid** and as you've defined **raw_id** as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` it is an alias of the **rowid** column.

Comment: Oooo it is `row_id` not `raw_id` it makes more sence now thanks for the answer it is exactly what I wanted

Comment: @KyriafinisBill you can user **rowid** **oid** or **_rowid_** (can never remeber the 2nd and 3rd off-hand so always use **rowid** (it's official name)). e.g. you can use `SELECT *,rowid AS my_dynamic_alias_for_the_rowid FROM ......` (you need **AS** something when retrieving)